# xsl:copy-of excluding parent together with replace

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Good afternoon! It's been a while since I've done XSLT and am a bit stumped. Trying to achieve the following:

When applied to the following xml..

```
<tag>
  content
  <br />
</tag>
```

*would produce this result:*

```
modified content
<br />
```

In other words, I'm trying to grab/output all contents on the main tag, including HTML but with a modified content item. Just selecting the element content is dead simple with a `<xsl:copy-of select="./node()"/>` and so is replacing the "content" with something else, but I can't seem to figure out how to combine the two. I'm also using XSLT 1.0 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag/text()[contains(., 'content')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('modified ', .)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course if any first child text node of `tag` elements need to be manipulated then you could change the third template to say

```
<xsl:template match="tag/text()[1]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('modified ', .)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! I tried the above and while it does modify the tag's value (content -> modified), it doesn't carry over the <br /> tag, unfortunately. I'm using it like this (although I tried simply removing everything and using your templates above too):

<xsl:template match="tag">
    <xsl:when test="normalize-space()='content'">
        <!-- I tried inserting a call to your template here,
             but it only carries over the modified text and no node.
        -->
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:template>

Comment: A stylesheet with the three templates I posted will copy the `br` element over as the first template does that when the template with `match="tag"` does an `apply-templates`. So as far as your snippets of input where posted you don't need anything but the three templates.

Comment: All makes sense / works - thanks Martin, brief moment of insanity on my part!